# How to change/reset iPhone simulator device ID?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

How to change or reset an iPhone simulator device ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to generate an UUID, say to tag an upload or communication to your server as being from a specific device you can use the CFUUID class to generate a UUID the first time your application is run,

```
NSString *uuid = nil;
CFUUID theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (theUUID) {
  uuid = NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID);
  CFRelease(theUUID);
}
```

and then save this in your application preferences. This will then uniquely identify the users device, and it'll also work in the iPhone simulator.

Comment: do you know if I can use a udid of my real device on a simulator ?

Answer (score 5):

Solved.

```
@implementation UIDevice (ChangeUID)

- (NSString*)uniqueIdentifier
{
    return @"test";
}

@end
```

Comment: I want to configure my udid and your answer doesnt tell me how to do.